# Kohana config database - enabling

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-db

I can't make to Config_Database work.

I'm enabling new Config Source that way:

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database, FALSE);
```

I'm loading that source after loading modules - in the bottom of bootstrap.php file.

I get this error when I'm trying to enable this Config Source

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in /var/www/moje/modules/database/classes/kohana/config/database/writer.php on line 124
```

Line 124 in file (.../)database/writer.php doesnt exists - it has only 111 lines.

What's going wrong?

edit: Kohana 3.2

Comment: What is Config_Database? If you want to load the database config file, it should be just an associative array, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in 3.2 I have got it to work with 3.0 (haven't tried 3.1). Here's the thread in Kohana Forums:

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9637/config_database-and-the-out-of-memory-error/p1

Answer (score 0):

It's going because Kohana trying to load database settings from database (and it's going to recursion)

You should initialize your database instance before attaching `Config_Database` reader

Try this (in `bootstrap.php`, after `Kohana::modules()`):

```
Database::instance();

Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply load database config right before adding the Config_Database

```
Kohana::$config->load('database');
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database, FALSE);
```